# Using "alert" and "confirm" as variable names

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

According to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) and any other source I can find, "alert" and "confirm" are not reserved words in JavaScript.  Why are they not listed here, and are they safe to use as variable names inside of function bodies?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from overwriting built-in javascript functions, but it is a terrible idea to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are safe to use inside function bodies as long as you declare them with `var`. If you don't declare them with var, then you would overwrite them in the global (window) scope, which could cause a lot of issues.

Comment: Looks like you are right.  To test this, I popped open a Chrome console and ran this line: `(function(){ var alert = 'foobar'; })()`, then checked the value of the global alert by running `alert` which still returned the native alert function.

Comment: As another commenter posted, just be aware that if you wanted to use the global alert inside the function, you could reference it as window.alert

Comment: You may have also seen a pattern like `(function(widow,undefined) { }(window, undefined));` which is used to preserve the global objects for use inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

They are not listed because they are not reserved words.

`alert` and `confirm` are functions on the `window` object, which is the global scope in the browser. Because it is global, you can reference its properties as bare words.

```
//Equivalent
window.alert('test');
alert('test');
```

You can safely use them inside of functions. Doing so will hide the bare use, but you can still call `window.alert()` to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are not reserved words.

In ECMAScript 5, [reserved words](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) are:

- [Keywords](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1): `break`, `do`, `instanceof`, `typeof`, `case`, `else`, `new`, `var`, `catch`, `finally`, `return`, `void`, `continue`, `for`, `switch`, `while`, `debugger`, `function`, `this`, `with`, `default`, `if`, `throw`, `delete`, `in`, `try`.
- [Future Reserved Words](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2): `class`, `enum`, `extends`, `super`, `const`, `export`, `import`.  And, in strict mode, `implements`, `let`, `private`, `public`, `yield`, `interface`, `package`, `protected`, `static`.
- [Null Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.1): `null`
- [Boolean Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.2): `true`, `false`.

Since `alert` and `confirm` are identifier names and aren't reserved words, they are identifiers. Therefore, they can be used safely as variable names.

```js
var alert = 1,
    confirm = 2;
document.body.innerHTML = alert + confirm; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override these functions, nothing will stop you.

If you have a custom object or function:

```
var obj = { alert: 1, confirm: 2};
function func(){
    var alert = 1;
    var prompt = 2;
}
```

This is not a problem.

However, if you override the actual `alert` or `confirm` functions on the window object, you might get into trouble if you include libraries that depend on that functions.

In order to disable annoying `alert()` boxes, this can however be useful.

Answer (score 0):

They are not reserved words because they are "global" (properties of "window") functions.
Assigning values to them will result in losing their functionality in the same scope, e.g.:

```
alert = "sdfsdf";
...
alert("something");
```

will result in an error such as "TypeError: alert is not a function".